# Create a csv file based on variables in AWK

Tags: bash, csv, variables, awk

This looks to be relatively straightforward for some people, but in my case I have spent a lot of time and it doesn't work. The thing I want to do is to create a csv file delimited by comma using as information the name of the fastq in the list provided fastq_1 M1, fastq_2 M2 and variables. The name of the csv header should be as follows sample, fastq_1, fastq_2, strandedness and each variable and name must match in the same column of the header.

```
fastq folder

S1_1.fastq.gz
S1_2.fastq.gz
S2_1.fastq.gz
S2_2.fastq.gz 
S3_1.fastq.gz
S3_2.fastq.gz
S4_1.fastq.gz
S4_2.fastq.gz

# variables
sample="mouse"
M1=$(ls *_1.fastq.gz)
M2=$(ls *_2.fastq.gz)
strandedness="paired"

#code
awk '
BEGIN      { OFS=",";
             print "sample", "fastq_1", "fastq_2", "strandedness"
           }
FNR==NR    {
             print $sample, $M1, $M2, $strandedness
           }' > output.csv
```

Desired output

```
sample, fastq_1, fastq_2, strandedness  #header
mouse, S1_1.fastq.gz, S1_2.fastq.gz, paired #values
mouse, S2_1.fastq.gz, S2_2.fastq.gz, paired #values
mouse, S3_1.fastq.gz, S3_2.fastq.gz, paired #values
mouse, S4_1.fastq.gz, S4_2.fastq.gz, paired #values
```

I would be pleased if someone could help me to solve this problem

Comment: please update the question with the output from the following: `typeset -p sample fastq_1 fastq_2 strandedness`; while I'm assuming you're matching filenames (from `fastq_1` and `fastq_2`) it's not clear (yet) how you determine which files are to be matched sooo ...  please update the question with an explanation on how you determine which files are to be matched together, also provide details on what to do with files that cannot be matched (eg, add to them to the output but with a blank field for 'missing' file?)

Comment: I already updated it. @markp-fuso Basically `awk BEGIN { OFS=","; print "sample", "fastq_1", "fastq_2", "strandedness"}` is the header of the CSV file and what I want is that the values of `$sample` are included inside the column called `sample` and so on for the values

Comment: all you did was add the string `typeset -p` to your expected output; that does ***not*** show us what's in your variables; run `typeset -p sample fastq_1 fastq_2 strandedness` after the variables have been populated and before the `awk` call, then update the question with the complete set of output generated by the `typeset -p ...` call; also, your latest update shows your variables as a set of comma-delimited strings ... your earlier edits showed a mix of arrays and (undefined) strings ... which is it? solutions/ideas will vary based on strings vs arrays

Comment: @markp-fuso I have provided new information, I hope it can be readily understood

Comment: do you know with 100% certainty that your fastq files come in matching pairs (`_1` and `_2`)? if not, what are we supposed to do if a file does not have a match?  is the 'match' based on the first part of the filename before the underscore?  ​are there other filename formats that we need to be aware of?

Comment: No, all fastq files come in pairs `(1 and 2)` that way you could differentiate them, because they are the only files in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure bash might be easier than awk for that:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sample=mouse
strandedness=paired
fastq_folder=./
{
    # header
    printf '%s, %s, %s, %s\n' sample fastq_1 fastq_2 strandedness

    # values
    for fastq_1 in "$fastq_folder"/*_1.fastq.gz
    do
        fastq_2="${fastq_1%_1.fastq.gz}_2.fastq.gz"

        [[ -f $fastq_2 ]] || continue # you may display an error message

        printf '%s, %s, %s, %s\n' \
            "$sample" \
            "${fastq_1##*/}" \
            "${fastq_2##*/}" \
            "$strandedness"
    done
} > output.csv
```

output.csv:

```
sample, fastq_1, fastq_2, strandedness
mouse, S1_1.fastq.gz, S1_2.fastq.gz, paired
mouse, S2_1.fastq.gz, S2_2.fastq.gz, paired
mouse, S3_1.fastq.gz, S3_2.fastq.gz, paired
mouse, S4_1.fastq.gz, S4_2.fastq.gz, paired
```

**remark:** Adding a space after the commas may seem prettier, but in CSV terms, doing so is adding a space character to the data.

Comment: How can you redirect to a file like `output.csv`?

Comment: I edited the answer with a way to do that, but it's more convenient to not hard-code it in the script and just redirect the output when you launch it, like any other command

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls fastq_folder
S1_1.fastq.gz  S2_1.fastq.gz  S3_1.fastq.gz  S4_1.fastq.gz
S1_2.fastq.gz  S2_2.fastq.gz  S3_2.fastq.gz  S4_2.fastq.gz
```

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS=","
    print "sample", "fastq_1", "fastq_2", "strandedness"
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        sub(".*/","",ARGV[i])
        file1 = file2 = ARGV[i]
        sub(/_1/,"_2",file2)
        print sample, file1, file2, strandedness
    }
    exit
}
```

```
$ awk -v sample="$sample" -v strandedness="$strandedness" -f tst.awk fastq_folder/*_1.fastq.gz
sample,fastq_1,fastq_2,strandedness
mouse,S1_1.fastq.gz,S1_2.fastq.gz,paired
mouse,S2_1.fastq.gz,S2_2.fastq.gz,paired
mouse,S3_1.fastq.gz,S3_2.fastq.gz,paired
mouse,S4_1.fastq.gz,S4_2.fastq.gz,paired
```

The above assumes the files are always paired as you stated in a comment and there aren't so many files as to exceed the shell's ARGS_MAX.

Comment: As expected, for doing it with awk the easiest way is to process ARGV;  +1